# One Form create multiple data tables

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I have one form to create data and insert it into 3 different tables.
Below is my table relation.

[image: my table and example data]

**Controller**

```
public function storeKelas(Request $request)
{
    $req = $request->all();

    $idkel = $request->matkul;
    $allmodul = $this->idModul($idkel);
    $jenistugas = ['pre_test', 'post_test', 'laporan'];

    $kelas = new Kelas();
    $kelas->id_periode = $req['id_periode'];
    $kelas->id_matkul = $req['matkul'];
    $kelas->id_dosen = $req['dosen'];
    $kelas->nama_kelas = $req['name'];
    $kelas->kode_matkul = $req['kode'];
    $kelas->save();

    foreach ($allmodul as  $modul) {
        $modulkelas = [
            'id_kelas' => $kelas->id_kelas,
            'id_modul' => $modul,
            'created_by' => Session::get('user_id'),
            'id_periode' => $req['id_periode'],
        ];
        ModulKelas::create($modulkelas);
    }

    foreach ($jenistugas as $key =>  $tugas) {
        $tugasmodul = [
            'id_kelas' => $kelas->id_kelas,
            'jenis' => $tugas,
            'id_periode' => $req['id_periode'],
            'id_modulkelas' => $modulkelas['id_modulkelas'],
            'created_by' => Session::get('user_id'),
        ];
        Tugas::create($tugasmodul);
    }

    return redirect('kelas')->with('success', 'Kelas Baru Sudah dibuat');
}
```

**Error**
[image: error!]

However, when I check the `kelas` table and the `modulkelas` table, the data is created. The problem is when I try to create data for the `tugas` table.

Comment: As per the code `$modulkelas['id_modulkelas']` using to create tugas record but `id_modulkelas` is not set in the `$modulkelas` array. only `$modulkelas = [

            'id_kelas' => $kelas->id_kelas,
            'id_modul' => $modul,
            'created_by' => Session::get('user_id'),
            'id_periode' => $req['id_periode'],
        ];` is there.

Comment: id_modulkelas is primarykey and autoincrement

Comment: it might be auto increment but it is not being assigned inside the first foreach. Not only that, you might have created multiple `ModulKelas` data but the array `$modulkelas`'s key value is only the last iteration of foreach `$allmodul`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering is likely because you're trying to access `'id_modulkelas'` from the `$modulkelas` array outside of the loop where it's defined. This means that the `'id_modulkelas'` key doesn't exist in the `$modulkelas` array when you're trying to access it, hence the error.

To fix this, you should create the `Tugas` records inside the loop where you create the `ModulKelas` records. This way, you can use the ID of each newly created `ModulKelas` record to create the corresponding `Tugas` records.

```php
public function storeKelas(Request $request)
{
    $req = $request->all();

    $idkel = $request->matkul;
    $allmodul = $this->idModul($idkel);
    $jenistugas = ['pre_test', 'post_test', 'laporan'];

    $kelas = new Kelas();
    $kelas->id_periode = $req['id_periode'];
    $kelas->id_matkul = $req['matkul'];
    $kelas->id_dosen = $req['dosen'];
    $kelas->nama_kelas = $req['name'];
    $kelas->kode_matkul = $req['kode'];
    $kelas->save();

    foreach ($allmodul as  $modul) {
        $modulkelas = ModulKelas::create([
            'id_kelas' => $kelas->id_kelas,
            'id_modul' => $modul,
            'created_by' => Session::get('user_id'),
            'id_periode' => $req['id_periode'],
        ]);

        foreach ($jenistugas as $key =>  $tugas) {
            $tugasmodul = Tugas::create([
                'id_kelas' => $kelas->id_kelas,
                'jenis' => $tugas,
                'id_periode' => $req['id_periode'],
                'id_modulkelas' => $modulkelas->id_modulkelas,
                'created_by' => Session::get('user_id'),
            ]);
        }
    }

    return redirect('kelas')->with('success', 'Kelas Baru Sudah dibuat');
}
```